# ExcelからRDS MySQLにODBC接続するために

Tags: vba, aws, excel

ただいまVBAを使ってExcelからRDSまたはEC2上のMySQL DBに接続しようかとサーチしています。これまでローカルまたはオンプレミスのODBC接続は経験があるのですが、AWSに接続したことがありません。どなたかご存知な方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

VBAでSERVERを設定しますが、そこにAWSのDNS情報やRDSのエンドポイントを書いて試しましたがうまくいきませんでした。。。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: もしよければ現状どういうソースコードになっているかも(機密部分は伏せて)質問文に含めると、解答がつきやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 念のため確認したいのですが。 ODBCを使わない(例えば通常のmysqlクライアントでの接続)はできていますか？　ODBCは共通インターフェイスなので接続そのものの問題とODBC設定の問題を切り分けた方が良いと思います。

Comment: たぶん、 AWS Secutiry Group の設定で Inboud の 3306 が通ってないのでは？という気がします。